# Fedora 37 on Intel Intgrated graphics doesn't have an option to use 1440p resolution at 120hz

Tags: fedora, xorg, intel-graphics, resolution, hdmi

I have Fedora 37 on my old PC in which I’m trying to get 1440p at 120hz working.
I have an I[ntel core i7 3770s CPU](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/65524/intel-core-i73770s-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz/specifications.html), no external GPU (using intel integrated graphics), my [motherboard is a P8H77-V](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/p8h77v/helpdesk_cpu/), and the monitor [I’m using is an AORUS AD27QD](https://www.gigabyte.com/Monitor/AORUS-AD27QD/sp#sp) which fully supports 1440p at 120htz, and in fact works on my Windows 11 PC. I’ve also made sure the HDMI cable I’m using is a highspeed one (the one that came with an Xbox One X), so it should easily support 1440p at 120hz. I’m using gnome on Xorg due to other software restraints, so I can’t really switch to Wayland or others.

I’ve ran a few commands I found on the internet which might be helpful.

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 609mm x 355mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation IvyBridge GT2 [HD Graphics 4000] (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: i915

$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
```

I also tried to change the resolution and refresh rate with `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-3 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --rate 120
xrandr: cannot find mode 2560x1440
```

Any help would be appreciated since I have no idea.

Comment: Not sure HD 4000 supports anything above 1080p via HDMI: https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Intel-HD-4000-HDMI-2560x1440-resolution/td-p/375068  https://superuser.com/questions/964703/what-is-the-maximum-display-resolution-on-the-intel-hd-graphics-4000-chipset-on

Comment: That would appear to be the case. Thanks. If you move your comment to an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it detects one screen and not the other. This is my way of adjusting the resolution of my screen after knowing the name of my screen using the "xorg" command in this case the name is: DP-2.

```bash
xrandr --newmode "resolution" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

```bash
xrandr --addmode DP-2 "resolution"
```

```bash
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode "resolution"
```

Running the three commands directly (using `&&`):

```bash
xrandr --newmode "resolution" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync &&\
xrandr --addmode DP-2 "resolution" &&\
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode "resolution"
```

Now what I want is to create a script that automatically runs on startup and I can't manage to do it.